# Error: "Query" defined in resolvers, but not in schema

Tags: reactjs, node.js, graphql

<----UserTypeDef----->

``const userTypeDef = `#graphql
type User {
_id:String!
username:String!
name:String!
password:String!
profilePicture:String
gender:String!

```
}

type Query {
    users:[User!]
    authUser:User
    user(userId:ID!):User
}
type Mutation {
    signup(input:SignupInput!):User
    login(input:LoginInput!):User
    logout:LogoutResponse
}

input SignupInput{
    username:String!
    password:String!
    gender:String!
}
input LoginInput{
    username:String!
    password:String!
}
type LogoutResponse{
    message:String!
}
```

;
export default userTypeDef;``

<----My UserResolver---->

``import {users} from "../dummyData/Data.js"

const userResolver = {

```
Query:{
    users: ()=> users
},
Mutation:{}
```

}``

export default userResolver;`

----->Dummy Data----->

`const users = [ { _id: "1", username: "user1", name: "User One", password: "password1", profilePicture: "profile1.jpg", gender: "male", }, { _id: "2", username: "user2", name: "User Two", password: "password2", profilePicture: "profile2.jpg", gender: "female", }, { _id: "3", username: "user3", name: "User Three", password: "password3", profilePicture: "profile3.jpg", gender: "male", }, { _id: "4", username: "user4", name: "User Four", password: "password4", profilePicture: "profile4.jpg", gender: "female", }, { _id: "5", username: "user5", name: "User Five", password: "password5", profilePicture: "profile5.jpg", gender: "male", }, ];`

It giving:  throw new Error(`"${typeName}" defined in resolvers, but not in schema`);
Error: "Query" defined in resolvers, but not in schema

Comment: Okay i have fixed it. Problem was in mergedTypeDefs.